# unknown error in jython when use startswith()

Tags: python, jython, startswith

I'm using python to analyze some records bib and ris files. I made two functions for each type. The first function is the one you see below:

```
def limpiarlineasris(self, data):
    cont = data
    dic = cont.splitlines()
    cont = ""
    con = []
    i = 0
    for a in dic:

        if len(a) != 0:
            con.append(a)

    for a in con:
        cont = cont + a + "\n"
    return cont
```

That works well and I can compile without problem. The problem arises when I write the second function see below:

```
def limpiarlineasbib(self, data):
    cont = data
    dic = cont.splitlines()
    cont = ""
    con = []
    separador = "°-°-°"
    for a in dic:
        if len(a)!= 0:
            if a.startswith('@'):
                con.append(separador)
            else:
                con.append(a)
        for a in con:
            cont = cont + a + "\n"
    return cont
```

When building the first function no problem. But when I compile the second compiler shows me an error but does not tell me exactly what or where it is because I am using plyjy a jar to create Jython objects, and the console only shows me an exception Plyjy without the line where it occurs. I'm using Netbeans to compile

Comment: There may be an issue with your `separador` string, which contains non-ASCII characters. What happens if you replace that with something simpler?

Comment: That was the problem. But I saw Jython use Python 2.x and I have installed Python 3.4..